# Problem attaching same Entity with same Primary Key to DbContext in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, unit-of-work

I'm developing a .NET Core 3.1 Razor Page Application. I'm using Entity Framework Core and a Unit of Work pattern with Generic Repository. I'm also using AddScoped to register all my services, e.g. UnitOfWork and Repositories etc., i.e., one DbContext shared amongst repositories per HttpRequest.

```
services.AddDbContextPool<MyContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection"))
         .EnableSensitiveDataLogging());

services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
services.AddScoped<IGenericRepository<Domain.List>, ListRepository>();
services.AddScoped<IGenericRepository<Domain.ListItem>, ListItemRepository>();
//etc...
```

I've written some code for a user to update their name and email. Once the user enters the data, I call a function UserAlreadyExists to validate if the email address already exists in the database. This validation code is used for new users registering on the application, but also for users who are already registered and are updating their details. The below code is used when an existing user is attempting to update their details.

```
public IUnitOfWork UoW { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public Domain.User UserObj { get; set; }

public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(UserObj.Id > 0)
        {
           //Update user

           //Validation to ensure if email updated, it's not already in use
           if(UserAlreadyExists(UserObj))
           {
              TempData["Message"] = "Email address already exists within database.";
              return Page();
           }

           UoW.UserRepository.Update(UserObj);
           UoW.SaveChanges();
           TempData["Message"] = "User updated.";

        }
        else
        {
          //Add user code here               
        }

        return RedirectToPage("List");
    }

   return Page();
}
```

This is the code that checks for the user's existence

```
private bool UserAlreadyExists(Domain.User user)
{
   bool alreadyExists = true;

   var existingUser = UoW.UserRepository
            .Find(u => u.Email.Trim().ToUpper() == user.Email.Trim().ToUpper())
            .FirstOrDefault();
        
    // Existing user
    if (existingUser == null)
    {
        alreadyExists = false;
    }
    else if (user.Email == existingUser.Email)
    {
        if (user.Id == existingUser.Id)
        {
            //User updating their details, but not their email
            alreadyExists = false;
        }               
    }

   return alreadyExists;
}
```

When an existing user tries to update their name, I get this error:

> The instance of entity type 'User' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached

I understand the error, and it's happening inside the `UserAlreadyExists` function. When an existing user attempts to update their name, the `User` entity is passed into the function and that entity contains the primary key. Then I create another `User` entity within the validation function called `existingUser`, and this is where the problem is - I now have 2 user entities with the same primary key value.

I'm wondering should I just detach the `existingUser` entity from the context prior to save changes, or maybe there is a better approach?

Any feedback appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What if you were to just query for the count of records where the email matches and the ID matches. If the result is 0 then return false, otherwise return true.

Comment: @Serge That's a strange comment. Unit of Work and Generic Repository Patterns are used successfully in web applications across the globe. Such patterns are taught on Pluralsight and by Microsoft when developing .NET and .NET Core Applications.

Comment: @tcode `That's a strange comment.` quite the opposite, putting a "generic repository" (it's actually a DAO) on top of an ORM like EF Core is a notorious antipattern that causes a *ton* of problems. I've encountered at least 3 questions caused by this just today. A DbContext *is already a Unit-of-Work*, a DbSet is *already a Repository*. Right now we have no idea what your code does. There's no code that attaches the entity. We have no idea what `UserAlreadyExists` although I suspect it loads the entity you want to update, thus causing the error.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I believe I did post the "relevant" code, and enough text description. Yes, I know what was causing the problem but was asking for other opinions on how to resolve it as I wasn't sure what I was proposing was the best approach. I think it's best we leave this discussion as it is, however, a read over this would do no harm https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem was to use Entity Framework's `.AsNoTracking`.

The initial query below was tracked by EF, but there was no need to do so, this entity was only being used for comparison purposes, therefore the DbContext did not need to track it.

```
var existingUser = UoW.UserRepository
            .Find(u => u.Email.Trim().ToUpper() == user.Email.Trim().ToUpper())
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Instead, I created a method (below) in my User Repository that took advantage of the `.AsNoTracking` functionality:

```
public User GetUserByIdNoTracking(int Id)
{
   return context.Users.AsNoTracking().Where(u => u.Id ==Id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And then used this in my `UserAlreadyExists` method.

```
//This entity is not tracked by the DbContext, there is no need, used only for comparison check
var existingUser = UserRepository
.GetUserByEmailNoTracking(email);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what the `UoW` and `UserRepository` classes do. The error is caused because `UserAlreadyExists` loads the entity but doesn't update it.  From the error it looks like `UserRepository.Update` is trying to attach the DTO again, even though the entity with the same ID is already loaded.

There are two options:

- Only load the `ID` instead of the entire entity
- Update the loaded object

**Load only the ID**

If EF Core was used directly, `UserAlreadyExists` could be rewritten to check for existence using LINQ:

```
private bool UserAlreadyExists(Domain.User user)
{
    var id=await _context.Users.Where(u=>u.Email==user.Email.Trim())
                         .Select(u=>u.Id)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
    return (user.Id==id);
}
```

That's all it takes, because `user.Id` is already known to be >0, and the emails already match.

`u.Email` should *not* be modified because that prevents the database server from using any indexes to speed up searching for the email. In SQL Server it's common to use case-*in*sensitive collations so there's no reason to use `ToLower()`.

After that, whatever `Update` does should work, because there's no entity being tracked. If EF Core was used, we could write:

```
if(!UserAlreadyExists(UserObj))
{
    _context.Users.Update(UserObj);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Update the loaded entity**

The [Razor CRUD tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/crud?view=aspnetcore-5.0#update-the-edit-page) shows how to use the [ControllerBase.TryUpdateModelAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/crud?view=aspnetcore-5.0#tryupdatemodelasync) method to update an already loaded entity. Instead of checking if a user exists, we can load the entity directly and update it:

```
var existingUser= _context.Users.Where(u=>u.Email==UserObj.Email.Trim())
                               .FirstOrDefault();
if(existingUser==null)
{
    _context.Users.Add(UserObj);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
else if(existingUser.Id==UserObj.Id)
{
    if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<User>(existingUser))
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

`TryUpdateModelAsync` will use the Model properties so it doesn't need access to the `UserObj` object.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in the end of the day, entity's db context is both a unit of work ( mind your injections ) and a generic repository for all models defined in the context, so.. you can actually go by without re-wrapping everything on something you will have to maintain later.

For this scenario, since you probably dont have the "AsNoTracking" available ( due to not working directly with ef as your repo ), you can change the code in 2 ways:

1. perform a count on the db, with the filters you want, so that you
   return the logical "is there a user already" instead of the actual
   user row
2. perform a select over a DTO object, that is an object
   that is not actually been tracked. Make a projection, select the
   properties you want to select, and map them to a plain class,
   specific for the task

Answer (score 0):

```
var btable = db.BlogTables.AsNoTracking().Where(a=> a.Id == bt.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

I faced same problem but when I have added the AsNoTracking function it is resolved.